# Where do you perform your validation?

Tags: validation, architecture

Hopefully you'll see the problem I'm describing in the scenario below. If it's not clear, please let me know.

You've got an application that's broken into three layers,

- front end UI layer, could be asp.net webform, or window (used for editing Person data)
- middle tier business service layer, compiled into a dll (PersonServices)
- data access layer, compiled into a dll (PersonRepository)

In my front end, I want to create a new Person object, set some properties, such as FirstName, LastName according to what has been entered in the UI by a user, and call PersonServices.AddPerson, passing the newly created Person. (AddPerson doesn't have to be static, this is just for simplicity, in any case the AddPerson will eventually call the Repository's AddPerson, which will then persist the data.)

Now the part I'd like to hear your opinion on is validation. Somewhere along the line, that newly created Person needs to be validated. You can do it on the client side, which would be simple, but what if I wanted to validate the Person in my PersonServices.AddPerson method.  This would ensure any person I want to save would be validated and removes any dependancy on the UI layer doing the work. Or maybe, validate both in UI and in by business server layer.  Sounds good so far right?

So, for simplicity, I'll update the PersonService.AddPerson method to perform the following validation checks
- Check if FirstName and LastName are not empty
- Ensure this new Person doesn't already exist in my repository

And this method will return True if all validation passes and the Person is persisted, False if Validation fails or if the Person is not persisted.

But this Boolean value that AddPerson returns isn't enough for me at the UI layer to give the user a clear reason why the save process failed. So what's a lonely developer to do? Ultimately, I'd like the AddPerson method to be able to ensure what its about to save is valid, and if not, be able to communicate the reasons why it's not invalid to my UI layer.

Just to get your juices flowing, some ways of solving this could be: (Some of these solutions, in my opinion, suck, but I'm just putting them there so you get an understanding of what I'm trying to solve)

- Instead of AddPerson returning a boolean, it can return an int (i.e. 0 = Success, Non Zero equals failure and the number indicates the reason why it failed.
- In AddPerson, throw custom exceptions when validation fails. Each type of custom exception would have its own error message. In addition, each custom exception would be unique enough to catch in the UI layer
- Have AddPerson return some sort of custom class that would have properties indicating whether validation passed or failed, and if it did fail, what were the reasons
- Not sure if this can be done in VB or C#, but attach some sort of property to the Person and its underlying properties. This "attached" property could contain things like validation info
- **Insert your idea or pattern here**
- **And maybe another here**

Apologies for the long winded question, but I definately like to hear your opinion on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Multiple layers of validation go well with multi-layer apps.

The UI itself can do the simplest and quickest checks (are all mandatory fields present, are they using the appropriate character sets, etc) to give immediate feedback when the user makes a typo.

However the business logic should have the lion's share of validation responsibilities... and for once it's not a problem if this is "repetitious", i.e., if the business layer re-checks something that should already have been checked in the UI -- the BL should check all the business rules (this double checks on UI's correctness, enables multiple different UI clients that may not all be perfect in their checks -- e.g. a special client on a smart phone which may not have good javascript, and so on -- and, a bit, wards against maliciously hacked clients).

When the business logic saves the "validated" data to the DB, *that* layer should perform its own checks -- DBs are good at that, and, again, don't worry about some repetition -- it's the DB's job to enforce data integrity (you might want different ways to feed data to it one day, e.g. a "bulk loader" to import a number of Persons from another source, and it's key to ensure that all those ways to load data always respect data integrity rules); some rules such as uniqueness and referential integrity are really best enforced in the DB, in particular, for performance reasons too.

When the DB returns an error message (data not inserted as constraint X would be violated) to the business layer, the latter's job is to reinterpret that error in business terms and feed the results to the UI to inform the user; and of course the BL must similarly provide clear and complete info on business rules violation to the UI, again for display to the user.

A "custom object" is thus clearly "the only way to go" (in some scenarios I'd just make that a JSON object, for example). Keeping the Person object around (to maintain its "validation problems" property) when the DB refused to persist it does not look like a sharp and simple technique, so I don't think much of that option; but if you need it (e.g. to enable "tell me again what was wrong" functionality, maybe if the client went away before the response was ready and needs to smoothly restart later; or, a list of such objects for later auditing, &c), then the "custom validation-failure object" could *also* be appended to that list... but that's a "secondary issue", the main thing is for the BL to respond to the UI with such an object (which could also be used to provide useful non-error info if the insertion did in fact succeed).

Comment: What about testability ? Consider a contrived example, which is an 
oversimplified version of what I had seen in an unrelated app.

"Shopping.com" creates coupons/promos on their website with their 
internal web app "Genie". The shortest promo genie can create will 
be valid for 6 hours after it was published. To create (not publish) 
a promo, genie makes an api call which sends the expiryDateTime, 
among other things, to the backend. Note that the 6 hour business rule 
cannot be changed for some good reasons.....(refer next comment.)

Comment: In genie, we want to TEST if a message box is shown under the promo when it expires. I thought about the impact on testing when we use the two design approaches below for creating promos - 

***ONE***
- UI checks if expiryDateTime is at least 6 hours or more from current time & less than one month away. It then passes, expiryDateTime to backend.
- Backend only checks if expiryDateTime is between current time & one month.

***TWO***
- Backend checks if the expiryDateTime is between 6 hours from now & one month.....(refer next comment.)

Comment: Testing in the two approaches -
***ONE*** - Use the api call to backend to set expiryDateTime to a few minutes from current time.

***TWO*** - Send an api call to the backend & wait for 6 hours to test the expiry.
Alternately, hit the database layer directly & change expiryDateTime there, if its allowed.

Answer (score 4):

Just a quick (and hopefully helpful) comment: when you're wondering where to place validation, try pretending that, soon, you're going to completely recreate your UI layer using a technology you're not yet so familiar with**.  Try to keep out of that layer any validation-like business logic that you know for certain you'd have to rewrite in the new technology.

You'll find exceptions - business logic that ends up in your UI layer regardless, but it's a useful consideration nonetheless.

** Mobile dev, Silverlight, Voice XML, whatever - pretending you don't know the technology of your "new" UI layer helps you abstract your concerns and get less mired in implementation details.

Answer (score 3):

The only important points are:

- From the perspective of the front-end(s), the Middle Tier must perform **all** validation, you never know whether someone is going to try circumventing your front-end validation by talking directly to your Middle Tier (for whatever reason)
- The Middle Tier may elect to delegate some of that validation to the DB layer (e.g. data integrity constraints)
- You may optionally duplicate some validation in the UI, but that should only be for the sake of performance (to avoid round-trips to the Middle Tier for common scenarios, such as missing mandatory fields, incorrectly formatted data, etc.) These checks should **never** take the place of doing them in the Middle Tier

Answer (score 2):

Validation should be done at all three levels.

When I am in a project I assume I am making a framework, which most of the time is not the case.  Each layer is separate and must check all layers input before doing an operation

Each level can have a different way of doing it, it is not necessary they all use the same, but ideally they should all use the same validation with the ability to customize it.

You never want to let bad data into the database.  So you can never trust the data you are getting from the business layer.  It needs to be checked.

In the business layer you can never trust the UI layer, and you must check it to prevent un-needed calls to the database layer.  The UI layer works the same way.

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with David Basarab's comment that the same validations should be present in all layers. This defies the paradigm of responsibility of layers for one reason. Secondly, though the main intention is to make the layers (or components) loosely coupled, it is also important that a level of responsibility (and hence trust) is endowed on the layers. Though it might be necessary to duplicated some validations in UI and Business Layer (since UI layer can be bypassed by hacking attempts), however, it is not advisable to repeat the validations in each layer. Each layer should perform only those validations which they are responsible for. The biggest flaw in repeting validations in all layers is code redundancy, which can cause maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of this is more style than substance.  I personally favor returning status objects as a flexible and extensible solution.  I would say that I think there are a couple classes of validation in play, the first being "does this person data conform to the contract of what a person is?" and the second being "does this person data violate constraints in the database?"  I think the first validation can, and should be done at the client.  The second should be done at the middle tier.  With this division, you may find that the only reasons the save could fail are 1)violates a uniqueness constrains, or 2)something catastrophic.  You could then return false for the first case, and throw an exception for the other.

Answer (score 1):

If tier R is closer to the user (or any input stream you don't control) than tier S then tier S should validate all data received from tier R. This does not mean that tier R shouldn't validate data. It's better for the user if the GUI warns him he's making a mistake before he attempts a new transaction. But no matter how bulletproof the validation in your GUI is, the next tier up should not trust that any validation has taken place.

This assumes your database in completely under your control. If not, you have bigger problems.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you could have the UI pass the data needed to build a Person object through some sort of PersonBuilder object, so that object creation is consolidated in the domain/business layer, and you can keep the Person object in a state that is always consistent. This makes more sense for more complex entities, however even for simple ones, it is good to centralize object creation, just like you centralize persistence, etc.