# Should field length be made dynamic by fetching the length using a stored procedure?

Tags: c#

In a web application (C# + [SQL Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server)), is it good practice for the maximum field length of the fields in the user interface to be determined by the fields fetched from database?

Is it a good approach? If not, please mention the disadvantages.

Comment: which fields? are you talking about input boxes,textareas and all?

Comment: Yes you are right .(All the user input components in C#).

Comment: Why not? If it's JUST the maximum field length, it might be more useful as a setting than as a whole DB table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like overkill, unless you have a some very special reason to do so.

I assume, you would do this by getting the length from the database and then setting it dynamically on the HTML elements.

Disadvantages depend on usage and necessity:

1. For a high volume application with a lot of data and fields to display, this would mean many reads from the database and added processing just to render the UI.
2. It means there is a high dependency of the UI on the database, which sounds like regression given current practices and technologies that drive towards decoupling the UI from the database/backend
3. It is unnecessary in the presence of many methods of validation, from UI to middleware
4. You also wouldn't normally design a UI element to be the exact length as that of the database... What happens if the database field length is such that it messes up the UI? With that hardcoupling, you will have lost the ability and control of your UI.
5. Linked to point 4), it would be mean more work is required to make your UI more responsive and visible across devices without issues, since your database determines form field lengths.
6. Linked to point 5), it would mean if you were to change the field length in the database, then your UI is immediately impacted... or is at risk of being impacted. More work for maintenance. If the field length was increased to cater for a new requirement, in a different system using the same database, then you will have to fix the UI that will depend on those lengths... Or compromise it to cater for the other... or compromise **both** systems.

One cannot fully rely on the UI or the middleware or the database to perform validation.

It would be nice if you stated your use case.

Some interesting links:

1. [How to design a database for User Defined Fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106335/how-to-design-a-database-for-user-defined-fields)
2. [How to design a dynamic form with fields that are taken from the database](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/63236/how-to-design-a-dynamic-form-with-fields-that-are-taken-from-the-database)
3. [Where do you perform your validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936296/where-do-you-perform-your-validation)
4. [Data input validation - Where? How much?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/81062/data-input-validation-where-how-much#)

Comment: Thanks for your comments.We are inline with your suggestions.Just wanted to get knowledge from the experts. Here is the sample use case. for example : The maximum length for the "username" text box in the login page should be fetched from the database dynamically, before it is loaded.Similarly, we need to implement across all the fields within our web application.

Comment: Why not do that in your business logic or middle layer. Validation is hardly ever done this way. Do you have a special reason why?

Comment: This is still under discussion.We want to gather expert's view on this topic before finalizing.Please continue your valuable suggestions.

Comment: Added more references for your question. When I said use case, I meant, in terms of what type of application you are designing...for what audience. Is it a system that generates a UI and DB fields, based on user input? (a plausable use case for your scenario...though painful)... or its one who's UI you control and determine?...etc

Comment: We control and determine the UI. All the controls and database are static.

Comment: Then, in my opinion, I see no reason to have it that way. Validation is redundant across all layers. So have it, at minimum in the middle or business logic error. With ASP.Net MVC, you can add annotations to define your limits. If it's a large application, this would be in a DTO that corresponds to your Entity object...if you like.

Answer (score 0):

**Two reasons you should not call a stored procedure for retrieving the maximum length of fields:**

1. This will downgrade the user experience. If the user entered a string greater than the maximum length then he/she shouldn't wait for the response that he's/she's exceeded the length. It should be instant.
2. There shouldn't be any unnecessary database call if you want to improve the performance of the application.

**Suggested Approach:**

- You should rather put a *JavaScript method* /*Some other front-end check* for validation of the maximum length.
- If your users are smart enough to disable the JavaScript code then you should put a check in C# code just before doing the intended operation with the captured value.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a framework for my web applications where this is one of the functionality implemented.

To implement this feature, I have done the following (I will not include any extra feature of the framework that I developed and am using):

- Made an interface `IDbMappable` which contained a properties `FieldName`, `TableName` (`TableName` can be left blank and then `TableName` of the containing `Page` will be used. If `FieldName` is set then `TableName` *must* be set on either control level or page level)
- Made custom control class (inheriting existing controls and implementing the `IDbMappable` interface) [`TextBox` control can be used for anything (and while saving the data will be tried to be converted to the datatype in the database), `CheckBox` for a boolean field, `DropDownList` for a foreign key field, etc.]
- When the page was loaded, if `TableName` property is set on page, then all the controls, whose `TableName` property is not set, will fetch their respective restrictions from database; For controls where `TableName` property is set on controls, each control will fire a separate query to the database to fetch its restrictions. (Restrictions are like maximum length, if blank is allowed or not, possible set of values from drop down list, etc.) [I have a base class for each page; my pages do not directly inherit from `System.Web.UI.Page` class, instead they inherit from my page class that inherits from `System.Web.UI.Page` class]

I have also added reading description for keywords, like:

- `[Email]` for any field that should contain valid email IDs only (regular expression was auto generated for these fields)
- `[Url]` for valid URLs (only URLs)
- `[Uri]` for valid URIs
- `[RegEx: expression]` for specifying a regular expression. [Note: square brackets were mapped by their opening and closing, so the expression can contain square brackets without any problems].

**Now, Pros and Cons of this approach**

**Pros**

1. This approach eliminated a lot of trivial tasks (like setting `MaxLength` of `TextBox`, loading values in the `DropDownList`, placing `RequiredFieldValidator`, etc.)
2. This increased my productivity a lot
3. Code looks neat and clean (only the required logic is there on the page; OK and some more)
4. I am lot more free to change database design and layout.

**Cons**

1. If we put/populate objects/properties/control like `MaxLength`, `RequiredFieldValidator`, etc. during design time, then these values are compiled and runs faster; in this case these information is loaded from database hence one or many database round trips are done
2. New developers/other team members mostly become confused where the values are coming from or why their field values are overwritten (this can be prevented by implementing like if the property is already set, then do not populate it; but I overwrite the properties)
3. Somewhat rigid architecture and may not work for a different type of application (I use this framework in enterprise applications; for websites I use a totally different approach to reduce bloating (HTML))

**Conclusion**

Depending on the type of application to be developed, this architecture can be a boon or curse. In a high traffic application, this definitely is a curse as it will increase the processing requirement and network communication required at the server level. But for most of the enterprise applications this is definitely a boon.

I am using this framework of mine for nearly five years now. It is in its third iteration of improvements and a fourth version is planned.

*Note:* before someone comments, I had implemented caching of fetched information (but that is somewhat complex to discuss here)

Answer (score 0):

A common approach is for your source code to define both the database sizes and the UI validation. For example, in Entity Framework, [you can put size constraints on the C# objects themselves](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256141(VS.100).aspx);

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;  

namespace MvcDA {
    [MetadataType(typeof(ProductMD))]
    public partial class Product {
        public class ProductMD {
            [StringLength(50),Required]
            public object Name { get; set; }
            [StringLength(15)]
            public object Color { get; set; }
            [Range(0, 9999)]
            public object Weight { get; set; }
          //  public object NoSuchProperty { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

This is enforced both in the database and in the user interface for very little effort.

If you are hand-rolling all your objects and queries, then you've opted out of a lot of free features -- that's OK, and there are good reasons to do it, but be aware that this is a solved problem if you take a more managed approach.